# Is it possible to show the title and link of a song that started from queue while using lavalink.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a disord.py music bot using lavalink.py for music streaming.  Right now whenever you have a queue of songs it will play through them all, but in order to see what song is currently playing you need to use a command for it. I want the discord bot to send an embed with the song name and link when the next song in the queue starts. I used to use youtube-dl for the music function but it has since stopped working. I'm not sure if I need to use the StartTrackEvent and if I do, I'm not sure how to actually implement it to where it will send a message in the discord channel. Also, my music code is in a cog if that makes much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

(*I'm new to SO, excuse me if my answer isn't super great*)

You would not need an event to do this (assuming you're using the commands extension.) You could make your queue command, and use `AudioTrack.title` and `AudioTrack.identifier` to get the track and Youtube identifier. Using the identifier you could link to the track with `https://youtube.com/watch?v=<identifier>`. An example of this would be:

```py
@commands.command(name="current",description="Shows the current playing song.",usage="current",aliases=['np','nowplaying'])
async def current(self,ctx):
     player = self.bot.lavalink.player_manager.get(ctx.guild.id)
     embed=discord.Embed(title=player.current.title,url=f"https://youtube.com/watch?v={player.current.identifier}")
     await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This would return an embed that contains the title of the current track, and a link to the site in the title.